# Ending a boolean Method from another method?

Tags: java

I have a `boolean` method that will run until returns `true`. And I have another method running inside of that method which can end it. Is that possible? I haven't found anything on here or on the internet of this. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public boolean run(...) {
end();
}

public void end() {
// do stuff
return;
}
```

I've tried to get this to work for a while now, but just can't. I even tried using a Boolean method to end the other one:

```
public boolean end() {
// do stuff
return true;
}
```

I can't add another return, or else it will get confused. It will only stop the `end()` method.

Is it even possible to make this happen? The reason I want this is because I want to have a simple `if` statement, which contains a method that will do everything I want then end it after. Maybe there's another way around this?

Comment: No, I'm still lost.  When you `return`, you return to the last point of execution (i.e. when `end()` returns, you return to the end of the `run` method).  What problem are you tackling?  Do you have a more concrete example?

Comment: @Makoto
Basically what I want, is if a specific thing happens in the `end()` method. It will stop the code from running in both the `end()` method as well as the `run()` method.

Comment: If it's an error scenario, throw an exception. Otherwise you'll just have to return a `boolean` from `end` and check the value in `run` to see if `run` should stop or not. But don't use the exception solution for normal behavior, that's not what they are for.

Comment: @BrendonButler `if( !end() ) return false;` or similar inside `run()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @BLaZuRE Something like that would work, or I could just make an `if` statement that has a return value at the end, but I wanted to have a simple `if` statement (one that has no brackets). So there would be less code. And I would be using the `end()` method a lot, so I don't want to have to write out `return true;` every time.

EDIT: I just re-read your message. The if statement I have, is already occupied, by `args.length == 0`.

Comment: Don't deliberately try to save yourself a few characters of code. Why would you care about that? Instead, optimize readability. An `if` statement is very easy to understand.

Comment: @IngoBürk I have an `if` statement, it's a simple one, and I wanted to keep it one line long.

Comment: I get that. My question is why you want to keep it one line long. If it gives you a headache and ultimatively leads to finding hacky workarounds, it surely was a bad idea (and the exception solution for non-error scenarios imho is nothing but a hack).

Comment: @IngoBürk I guess I'll just keep it as a standard `if` statement. I just love the look of simple if statements. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've dealt with thousands of lines of code.  I don't fuss over one line.  I actually sometimes add multiple lines just for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly entirely clear, but it sounds to me like you want to do a non-local exit. In that case, the only way to do this in Java is using Throwables. One way to do that could be like this:

```
class Exit extends RuntimeException {}

public void run() {
    try {
        /* Do your stuff, which may or may not entail calling end(). */
    } catch(Exit e) {
        return;
    }
}

public void end() {
    throw(new Exit());
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted question, but basically I wanted to use as little code as possible. What I have now is `if (args.length == 0) msg.args(sender, 1);` in the `args()` method, I have a return statement, but it doesn't end the `run()` method.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. `return` only exits the method it occurs in. That's why you need to use a "non-local" exit instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I guess I'll just make it a standard `if` statement, instead of slowing it down with a `throw exception`.

Comment: I don't quite see why this is the accepted answer if you decided to do exactly not what this answer suggested. But as long as you chose not to use exceptions… ;)

Comment: @IngoBürk It helped me decide on what I should do.